# Maths (ILP) puzzle from a programming contest

Tags: linear-programming, puzzle

[This programming contest puzzle](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=26&page=show_problem&problem=2492) concerns itself with "cards", each of which bears a certain pattern of either one circle, one square, one triangle,
two circles, two squares, etc. up to three circles, three squares, and finally three triangles -- all the `9` combinations, that is. Now, one can pick `3` cards (called `sets`) such that in each of the two characteristics -- the shape or the number thereof -- the cards are either all equal or all different.
One is to write a program to find out the largest number of `sets` that can be formed from the given set of card. Each set of cards is given as a pair from `1-3` and `circle-square-triangle`.
I started with the following thoughts. I collate all the cards that come in the test case into a `3x3` matrix, where e.g. $a_{11}$ is the total number of `one-circle`-type of cards, and analogously for the rest. All the three cards in a valid `set` now either come from a row, column, the two diagonals, or indeed from each individual cell of this matrix. This way, one obtains an integer program with inequality constraints, where the objective function is linear. (There are `3+3+9+2=17` variables and `9` inequality constraints.) I can feel though there is a  "shortcut" and I must be missing something. What do you think?

EDIT: actually there can be a total of `21` types of `sets` -- `3+3+9+6`, where the last `6` comes from choosing all "independent" cells from the matrix (i.e. distinct in both row and column).

EDIT: After some thinking, here are some updates.
If we could not form a `set` by taking three cards of the same type,
this problem could be nicely modeled as a network flow problem.
However, we can, therefore some greedy logic is required.
We notice that each card-type can participate in `5` different configurations -- one we'll call `trivial`, which is taking three cards of this type,
and four `non-trivial`, where at least one characteristic differs.
Now, what happens when there are four cards of type `x` (say, of type
`one-circle`). We would want to look into the four `non-trivial` configurations and see if we have enough to "send over" the four given cards to these respective configurations, to form 4 `sets`. If this condition does not hold, we are better off by just forming one `set` using 3 cards (with 1 left over) -- indeed, we better not "disturb" other cells. Let me see if I can translate this into an algorithm.

EDIT: I've made some progress on the problem. It goes like this. There are 21 configurations in all, and in the optimal solution we will be left off with a matrix such that for each of the "non-trivial" `12` configurations at least one cell is `0`, and none of the cells contains a number larger than `2`. Indeed, if there existed a configuration such that all the participating cells contain at least `1`, we could have improved our solution. That said, the residual matrix will be a `3x3` matrix consisting of entries `0-2`, i.e. we are dealing with a ternary number. I have already done some computations,
and there are exactly `1603` configurations that could serve as residual matrices. One of them is e.g.

```
2 0 1 
1 0 0 
0 0 0
```

This takes us to the idea of fixing some such configuration, and trying to solve an underdetermined system of linear equations with `9` rows and `21` variables. Do you think this might work?

EDIT: As it turns out, the rank of the above-mentioned `9x21` matrix is `9`, as shown here: https://matrixcalc.org/en/#rank%28%7B%7B1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0%7D,%7B0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3%7D%7D%29
Now, what does this mean in terms of solving the system? When I diagonalize it using e.g. Gaussian elimination, we'll have 9 diagonal non-zero entries. What to do with the other 12 variables though?

EDIT: answering my previous question, since diagonalization process would not depend on the RHS in any way, here is what we get with Gaussian elimination:

```
 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

That is, there are exactly `4` "trailing" ones to account for the "free" variables. What to do with those? We remind ourselves that the aim is to choose the variables that their sum is maximal.

EDIT: I got accepted with the optimizations based on the above observations.

Comment: Note that Set allows you choose any of the *six* diagonals, not just the two main ones. I.e. one circle three square two triangle is also a valid set.